# Is there a $\Sigma^0_3$ variant of the halting problem?

Tags: computability, halting-problem

In terms of the arithmetical hierarchy, the halting problem is known to be $\Sigma^0_1$-complete, and the so-called *universal halting problem*, is the problem of determining whether a given computer program will halt for every input, is known to be $\Pi^0_2$-complete.

Is there a natural $\Sigma^0_3$-complete variant of the halting problem?

Answer (score 7):

Here are some natural problems which are complete for $\Sigma^0_3$:

- Given $\langle M \rangle$, is $L(M)$ cofinite?
- Given $\langle M \rangle$, is $L(M)$ recursive?
- Given $\langle M \rangle$, is $L(M)$ regular?
- Given $\langle M \rangle$, is $L(M)$ context-free?

In all of these, $L(M)$ is the set of inputs on which $M$ halts.

See [these lecture notes](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F1-84628-477-5_46.pdf).

Comment: Not sure if it counts as a "natural" problem, but the $n$-th Turing jump of $\emptyset$ is complete for $\Sigma^0_n$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem